# Expected order of an element in $A_5$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose we pick every element from the Alternating group $A_5$ equally likely. What would be the expected order of the element?

My answer is $\frac{241}{60}$. This is because, we have $1$ element of order $1$(the identity), $15$ elements of order $2$(the product of two disjoint transpositions),$10$ elements each of order $3$ and $6$ (the three element cycles and products of three element cycles with a disjoint transposition), and $24$ elements of order $5$(the five cycles). So, using the definition of expectation, I should get the expected value as $\frac{1}{60}+\frac{15\times2}{60}+\frac{10\times3}{60}+\frac{10\times6}{60}+\frac{24\times5}{60}=\frac{241}{60}$.

Is the calculation right? Because, I saw the answer key to the problem saying that the answer is $\frac{211}{60}$. So, where am I wrong (or is the key wrong?) Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You say "and $6$" ? The order can only be $1,2,3,5$, so the $6$ is not correct.

Comment: Indeed, the product of a $3$-cycle and a transposition is not an even permutation.

Comment: Another mistake is that the number of $3$-cycles is not $10$ but $20.$ So the result is $\frac{1}{60}+\frac{15\times2}{60}+\frac{20\times3}{60}+\frac{24\times5}{60}=\frac{211}{60},$ like in the "answer key".

Comment: @DietrichBurde ok, got it. The element would then be odd, so not a part of the alternating group

Comment: vidyarthi yes, as said in my 1st comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been answered in the comments. The 2 answers below did not add anything.

Comment: I can delete my answer (which I wrote so that there is an answer not only in the comments).

Comment: @AnneBauval Actually, then you would make the object oif asking a question incorrect, for, I genuinely asked a doubt in my calculations, irrespective of whether the question is answered in the comments, or otherwise, the question is appropriate, in my view.

Comment: @DietrichBurde no need to delete. It would show a beginner where he may go wrong in calculations.

Comment: I retract the sentence "The 2 answers below did not add anything." of my last comment. Now, Dietrich's answer (+1) adds an interesting link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the corrections mentioned in the comments we indeed obtain the "desired result":
$$\frac{1\times 1}{60}+\frac{15\times2}{60}+\frac{20\times3}{60}+\frac{24\times5}{60}=\frac{211}{60}$$
I would like to add that one can determine the order of elements in the alternating groups as follows:

[Orders of the elements in the alternating group $A_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521956/orders-of-the-elements-in-the-alternating-group-a-n)

Answer (score 0):

As shown by the comments of @DietrichBurde and @AnneBauval, the number of elements of order $3$ is $20$(taking permutation among the three cycles into account) and the product of three cycles with disjoint transposition is not an even permutation. Therefore, the revised calculations would be the expected order$=\frac{1\times1}{60}+\frac{15\times2}{60}+\frac{20\times3}{60}+\frac{24\times5}{60}=\frac{211}{60}$ as desired by the answer key.